# How to short python for loop, from insert structure to flat structure?

Tags: python

I have a code as below:

```
items = []
for item in json.loads(json_result):
    items.append((item['pk']))
```

Is there a more elegant way to write it? From multiple lines to a flatter structure, these 3 lines are in [.......] one line.

what I want is to short three lines to only one line, actually, is to use a flat structure instead of insert structure. This problem have been sloved, thanks!

Comment: It is called list comprehension: `items = [item['pk'] for item in json.loads(json_result)]`. I do not understand the second part of your question. Please be more specific.

Comment: the for loop can not be more shorted now. However the line of code can be reduced

Comment: @DyZ I want to short the code to only one row. The code you wrote has been the answer I want.... Thanks and sorry for my unclear question.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal The shorter lines is what I want. A flatter structure is more elegant than multiple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does the same than:

```
items = [item['pk'] for item in json.loads(json_result)]
```

This is called a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
items = [item['pk'] for item in json.loads(json_result)]
```

Comment: That’s what I want! Thanks!